# Array to Excel 2007 using PHPExcel

Tags: php, arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, phpexcel

I have this 2 dimensional array that I want to export as an excel file using PHPExcel.

```
// create a simple 2-dimensional array
$data = array(
   1 => array ('Name', 'Surname'),
   array('Schwarz', 'Oliver'),
   array('Test', 'Peter')
);
```

The problem is that I cannot predict the number of keys in the array so it becomes hard to use this method

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', 'world!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D2', 'world!');
```

I am trying to generate a `for` loop that will do this, any help?

Comment: Have you looked at the fromArray() method rather than looping through your array and setting each individual cell?

Comment: Now imagine a case where you have
`array(1=>array('Schwarz', 'Oliver','Schwarz', 'Oliver','Schwarz', 'Oliver','Schwarz', 'Oliver','Schwarz', 'Oliver','Schwarz', 'Oliver','Schwarz', 'Oliver','Schwarz', 'Oliver','Schwarz', 'Oliver','Schwarz', 'Oliver'))` How would you go about it?

Comment: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($myArray, null, 'A1')`

Comment: @MarkBaker That will probably work. Let me try it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

PHPExcel has a built-in method for setting cells from an array in a single step:

```
$data = array(
    array ('Name', 'Surname'),
    array('Schwarz', 'Oliver'),
    array('Test', 'Peter')
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($data, null, 'A1');
```

Comment: Why null and A1(may used for starting) at fromArray() ?

Comment: @151291 - [reading the PHPExcel docs would tell you](http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/classes/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html#method_fromArray)

Answer (score 3):

for this I would use the function

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row, $text)
```

and run the foreach on the arrays indexes. Columns start at 0, rows at 1.

Answer (score 1):

this one may help:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue(PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($i).'1', $key);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue(PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($i+1).'2', $value);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: No. Please, post your actual data (or a part of it) here

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach instead when traversing an array , it will give you key=>value pair.

Please let me know if expect anything different.

Comment: No, it wont work, i thought you were getting associative array.